# sed wont recognize tab after parentheses

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file with two columns per row where each column is separated with a tab character:

```
foo1    foo2
foo3()  foo4
```

I would like to replace each tab (**but only those that are not as first character in new line**) with a new line. So in the end I would end up with:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3()
foo4
```

Im using sed like this:

```
sed "s/\b\t/\n/g"
```

And it works well unless there is a `)` character (and also others like `+ = / \` before the tab. So in this case I get:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3()  foo4
```

How to make sed so that it will recognize the tab even if it is located after the parentheses?

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xC7qJ2/7)

**EDIT:**

Linux 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP

sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: am I right in guessing that you simply want two column input file to be converted to single column? you can try commands like `grep -o '[^ \t]*' file`  , `xargs < file | tr ' ' '\n'` ,  `awk '{print $1 ORS $2}' file` and so on

Comment: please add the output from `uname -srv && sed --version` to your Q. Good luck.

Comment: also, remind me, what does `\b` stand for? Can't you just do `.\t` to be sure it's not the first char on the line? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, I added os and sed version. unfortunately `.\t` also eats the first letter in a preceding word.

Comment: @Sundeep, the commands you stated won't work, because I have quite long strings after the tab - there are white spaces, sometimes one, sometimes two

Comment: @JacobS then you need to provide a better sample input and output :)

Comment: @Sundeep, the input doesn't really matter here, because it is the problem of recognizing `( )` characters as word boundaries as Ibrahim mentioned in his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for input in this task. I have discovered that `perl` works better in this case. So in the end I end up with:

```
perl -p -e "s/(?<=\S)\t/\n/g"
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are only two columns in the file (2nd column doesn't contain tabs) you could also try this:

```
sed "s/\(^.*\)\t/\1\n/g"
```

Searches largest substring until the last tab on a line and adds a newline after it, dropping that tab.

Comment: thanks for reply, this one did catch the tab after parentheses, but it also replaced tabs in the beginning of the line

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis `()` are not part of word boundaries. [1](https://regex101.com/r/xC7qJ2/9)

Try to do it this way: `(?<=\S)\t` .

```
sed "s/(?<=\S)\t/\n/g"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xC7qJ2/12

**Update**

> As pointed out by @Sundeep, Sed does not seem to support Lookarounds.

Comment: Won't this replace also a tab that is a first character on a line?

Comment: sed doesn't support lookarounds

Comment: @Ibrahim, i think Sundeep is right. there is something with that sed.. maybe awk would be better for that purpose?

Comment: @JacobS Yes, he is right. I updated my answer. Awk seems like a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/RYipEx/1) with the multiline `m` flag then replace with new line `\n`

```
(?<!^)\t
```

It replaces every tab character not preceded by start of a line (`^`) by a new line character. The `m` flag allows `^` and `$` to also match start and end of a line respectively. Note that this can also work for any number of column separated by exactly one tab.

Use this command to make replacement:

```
sed -e 's/(?<!^)\t/\n/gm'
```

Comment: sed doesn't support lookarounds